# Why my css file is not loading in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am very new to Laravel, I have done the login blade file and I included CSS files but it's not loading CSS files, can you please help me where I made a mistake ..?

`users.blade.php`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('resources/css/user.css') }}">
```

Comment: put your file on `public` directory => `/public/resources/css/user.css`

Comment: @sta, i tried this one too but it's not loading

Comment: where is your physical file location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the `resources` folder, which is not exposed to the public, you'll have to compile your css so it lives in the `public` folder, which is the folder that anyone(including your frontend) can access using `https://your-url.tld/{public file path}`. There are 2 ways in which you can have your `user.css` file available for to your frontend:

#### One:

You can import your `user.css` file to the existing `resources/css/app.css` file:

```css
/* app.css file */
@import "../path/to/user.css";
```

#### Two:

You can compile `user.css` to a separate file, in case you want to use that file specifically on another layout or blade file instead of mixing it globally with the `app.css` file:

```js
// webpack.mix.js file
mix.js('...')
    .css('resources/css/user.css', 'public/css');
```

Then in your layout file:

```php
// app.blade.php file
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/user.css') }}">
```

Hope it helps.